# Exact meaning of "припизженный"

Tags: мат, значение

While checking Google translate for a better match for a quite popular German term (which I understand, but can't seem to translate 100% accurately into Russian), I was quite unprepared for the suggestions I got: [image]

It's not the profanity per se that surprised me, but rather the word "припизженный," which I've never heard - like never ever in my life. I have no idea what it can mean or how it's used. I asked my friends - it's looks like nobody from my generation knows that word. I've tried googling it, but what few explanations I've managed to find are incomplete, and none of them is in agreement with the others.

So, my question is - what exactly does "припизженный" mean?

Comment: The mat. And like any word in an inflected language, it can fall under  inflectional transformations and neologization. In the primitive and highly context-dependent  speech of the characters who use this. Вообщем, - от "пиздить", to hit, to beat...  Ударенный (на всю голову, например), прибитый или забитый (хоть гвоздь, хоть раб)... etc...  


P.S. Why the hell are all last the subjects here about this stupid mat, what the hell: >>>

Comment: @Пилум obscene lexicon is just another layer of human language. One can choose not to use such vocabulary all  - still a language learner who knows what does "охуевший" or "пиздабол" mean in some sense is just richer and definitely, by the definition, knows more than who does not.

Comment: +1, I also can not remember if I ever heard this word before. [ru.wiktionary.org](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9) lists it as a synonym of "ебанутый". And this is not a very new word - apparently it was around for at least 10 years: [lingvoforum.net](https://lingvoforum.net/index.php?topic=14932.175).

Comment: shabunc, мне кажется, их просто чрезмерно много в последнее время, именно таких вопросов :>

Comment: Alexander, about "synonyms"-etc in... this - it looks more like interjections, where any meaning can be included ... by all sorts of the apes. :> Well, anyway - it all very, really context-depended.... :> https://youtu.be/I-EzZ4o3its  :>

Comment: That's a problem with the Russian мат - any made-up word can exist and mean something - but it is not clear what specifically. My first instinctive guess for the meaning of "припизженный" was "downtrodden"/"забитый".

Comment: Какой смысл спрашивать о "точном смысле" малоупотребляемых матершинных форм? Они могут иметь смысл совершенно произвольный, в зависимости от контекста или намерений употребляющего. Вне контекста о смысле можно разве что гадать по созвучию с другими словами - возможно, по аналогии с "пришибленный" ("этот чувак какой-то припизженный"), а возможно, со "спизженный" ("у меня тут припизжен пакетик титановых шурупов"). С более устойчивыми словоформами, вроде "спиздить" или "отпиздить" таких вопросов не возникает именно из-за их устойчивости и употребимости.

Comment: @Headcrab весь вопрос именно в том, насколько устойчива эта словоформа.

Comment: @shabunc - Конечно устойчива — вы же видите, не только Гугл о ней знает.

Comment: @YellowSky я никогда не слышал этого слова а гугл про использование редких слов часто запутаывает ещё больше.

Comment: @shabunc Это не редкое слово, это довольно стандартный мат. Активно используется в низших социальных слоях для обозначения неадекватно себя ведущих людей.

Comment: Eugene, если носитель языка, модератор сайта, указал Вам на то, что Вам лучше писать на родном языке, зачем упорствовать? Увы, не каждый может объяснить нюансы своего языка на иностранном. Не вставайте в позу. Включите в себе самокритика. Вы на серьёзном сайте. Или Вам собственное эго важнее, чем общее дело?

Comment: @shabunc В качестве дополнения отмечу, что в Питере изредка употребляется однокоренное ругательство "припиздок". Это синоним более московского существительного "объёбок". (Оба термина -- усиленныe синонимы слова "мудак".)

Answer (score 7):

This is a variation of *припизднутый* and *припизденный* and is related to *припиздь* "quirk, eccentricity".

Drummond's dictionary defines it as "mad, crazy".

I would personally use it in the sense of "eccentric, weird".

I've heard all four variations, although *припизденный* sounds regional to me. *Припизднутый* and *припиздь* are cited in Drummond's dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

I've heard it and used it many times myself — the closest synonyms are *ебанутый*, *ёбнутый*, *мудацкий*. *Припи́здеть* is to 'beat/strike/knock down', *припи́зженный* means ‘deformed, ugly, weirdly abnormal, abnormally weird’. *Припи́зденный* is an alternative variant. The connotations are always negative.

Comment: Что-то вы не то объясняете. Припиздеть означает вообще-то "немного соврать", а бить, ударять, сбивать с ног-пИздить.

Comment: @Summersby Yes, that's a valid correction. _To beat_ is _пи́зд**и**ть_ (with various affixes), not _пизд**е**ть_, but they both turn into _пи́зженный_ anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of припизженный is extremely dependent on the context. It can mean:

- weird
- shy
- abused
- shell-shocked
- physically injured
- psychopathic

and much more in different situations. It's better to not use it at all if you don't know its subtle nuances.

Answer (score 0):

I grew up in the 1990s in a rather criminal neighborhood in Russia and heard this word pretty often at the time. Here is a typical example:

> ⁠— Слышь, не в курсах, чё Колян сегодня какой-то припизженный?
>
> ⁠— Да залупился на Короеда и леща у Макса выхватил.

The exact meaning, at least at that time and in that neighborhood, was: being in low spirits as a result of having been beaten or put in one's place.

Here's a perfect [example](https://youtu.be/JRoCSIOL2bs?t=568) of the use of припизженный. The coach starts enthusiastically giving advice and accidentally gets hit. Just look how he instantly gets припизженный. No, really watch this video clip — that's precisely what this word is about.

There's a difference from отпизженный. Отпизженный is beaten up, while припизженный is more about low morale.

Sometimes припизженный was used to say that someone was in low spirits AS IF they had been beaten.

The origin is obviously from пѝздить - beat.

The meaning and usage may have evolved since then.

Answer (score -1):

It's so informal and patois-ish, that two friends of mine (both native Russian speakers) gave me two different definitions when I asked them.
That's why I'd avoid using the word.

Answer (score -2):

Припизженный and ебнутый are swear words, so they're used in anger or mockingly or with some other malicious emotion. If someone calls you ебнутый, then they REALLY don't like you and want to offend you. Very often, these words are used by hooligans, bad kids, gopniks and the like. The reason to use them is to hurt someone's feelings, so often these words have no real meaning.

Answer (score -3):

I am here and will tell you all this porridge above my answer. Припизженный means crazy/mentally ill.
Text me if you want to know Russian words in a simple form, I will always help!

Answer (score -3):

When speaking about someone's attitude to life, actions, deeds, "припизженный" may be used to set out that a person is "wacky with the shade/tinge of humbleness", "zoned out", "airy-fairy", "distrait", "bonkers" etc. All in all, the person's actions can be rather positive. For example, one has a special affection for cats (in general it is a good foible) but keeps 20 cats in his house. Many people would label him so: "Он конечно хороший, но все-таки какой-то припизженный" - "He is a good man, of course, but airy-fairy, in a way". Or when someone is a kind of a nerd but has a success in studies/sciences, there would always be those who will declare him "zoned out" etc: "Да он хоть и умный, но какой-то припизженный" - "Notwithstanding his being smart, he is a kind of zoned out". On the whole, if someone is "припизженный", you can call such a person "Punchy". And I will strongly abide by the inference that the word in question is not intended to affront someone directly in his face, but to jeer at somebody behind his back.

There is another range of meanings of "припизженный":

- fastened, nailed on to (прибитый, прикрепленный, при#уяренный, при#уяченный) - картина, крепко припизженная к стене (a painting soundly nailed on to the wall);
- brought in, dragged in, hauled in (принесённый, при#уяренный, при#уяченный) - в углу стоял кем-то припизженный чемодан (a suitcase dragged in by someone was standing in the corner);
- having barged in/limped up (пришедший, приперевшийся) - он восседал в кресле, припизженный (in the sense of "припиздивший") раньше времени (he was seated in the chair, having limped up ahead of time) - *this usage is of marginal acceptance and can be opted to lay stress on someone's pointedly toying with words*;
- killed, bumped off, knocked off (убитый, ухлопанный, прикокошенный) - на подоконнике валялась припизженная муха (a bumped off fly was knocking about on the window-sill).

In addition, I'd like to notice that words "ёбнутый" and "припизженный" don't mean the same, whereas "ёбнутый" alludes more to aggressiveness in demeanour. I.e. "Не связывайся с ним, он же ёбнутый. Он всегда лупит девушек" - "You'd better not get mixed up with him, he is bat-shit crazy. He is in the habit of walloping his girls". Or "Он всегда попадает в какие-то передряги, потому что он ёбнутый" - "He always gets caught up in different troubles because he is just sick-as-fuck".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138548/discussion-on-answer-by-eugene-exact-meaning-of-).

Comment: For bad, wrong or poorly worded answers we have the downvote button and the edit button. The report button is for spam, abuse, hate speech and suchlike. Please don't mix them up. Thank you.

Comment: you Russian examples make sense to me, but their English explanations, as to me, don't quite get their meaning across.